# Cyclic reference found while evaluating the ThemeStyle property on element 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock'

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple WPF-application, which show a string-collection in ListView. On hovering on a row a tooltip with text appears:

[image]

After tooltip appeared and I use mousewheel to scroll vertically a *System.InvalidOperationException* with this message is thrown

> Cyclic reference found while evaluating the ThemeStyle property on element 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock'

The XAML contains a ListView, with a style, which shows a **ToolTip** for every row:

```
<Window x:Class="CylicDependencyWpfApplication.MainWindow"
...>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <TextBlock>tooltip</TextBlock>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="300" Header="Column1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Window>
```

The shown data comes for a **ObservableCollection**, which is set in constructor of MainWindow

```
public MainWindow()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = observableCollection;
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            observableCollection.Add($"item{i}");
        }
}
```

In order to better see the content of Exception I added a **DispatcherUnhandledException**-handler:

```
private void App_OnDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
        Exception ex = e.Exception;
        // System.InvalidOperationException
        string name = ex.GetType().FullName;
        // Cyclic reference found while evaluating the ThemeStyle property on element 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock'.
        string message = ex.Message;
}
```

What is the cause of the issue ? Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue occurs, because the style ist not only applied to TextBlocks of ListView, it also applied to the TextBlock in the ToolTip!! This add a tooltip to the textblock contained in the tooltip. Therefore this cycle occurs.

This can be fixed like this:

```
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TextBlock ToolTip="">tooltip</TextBlock>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
```

This way the style applied the tooltip not anymore to the textblock contained in tooltip.